# Отобразить процесс скачивания файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

Добрый день!

На одном из сайтов музыки видел интересную реализацию скачивания. Когда жмешь на кнопку "скачать", в футере сайта появляется процесс скачивания, а по его окончании сам файл падает в футер браузера (иначе говоря в загрузки), но уже скачанный. Меня это заинтересовало, т.к. обычно скачивание и отображение его процесса инициируется браузером. Сам сайт давно потерял и найти не могу.

Я предполагаю, что тут процесс завязан на кеше и что первоначальное скачивание делается аяксом, а потом вызывается родной для браузера способ (вроде `window.location = url`) и файл уже берется из кеша и готовый падает в папку с загрузками. Пробовал реализовать самостоятельно (играл с заголовками cache-control, etag; выводил после аякса в iframe) - не получается, файл качается дважды и не обращает внимание на кеш.

Есть идеи, как такое реализовать на js (+jQuery)?

**UPD**
Обратил внимание, что в Chrome аякс запрос возвращает 200 ответ, но после вставки в iframe (чтобы инициировать скачивание браузером) так же 200ый, т.е. файл качается снова. В Edge и IE после вставки в iframe идет ответ 304 (не изменено) и файл, не скачиваясь вновь, падает в загрузки. Видимо, бага хрома

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой способ у меня сработал. Тут правда без прогресс бара, только загрузка в браузер и выдача скачанного файла. Суть в том что бы после загрузки файла добавить скрытый фрейм с этим файлом на страницу.

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
        $('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault;
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.ajax({
                url: url, //Скачиваем файл
                success: function(data) {
                    $('body').append('<iframe  src="'+url+'" style="display: none;"></iframe>'); //Добавляем скрытый фрейм с тем же файлом
                }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>

    <a href="http://файл">Ссылка скачать</a>
```

Comment: На каком файле вы тестировали? Запустил сервер node, отдаю файл (400мб) так:
`res.sendFile(file);`
В итоге скачивается дважды. Еще вопрос - какой браузер? Сейчас решил проверить в Edge - вроде качает один раз. Изначально тестировал в Хроме

Comment: Браузер хром. Файл 40 мб. Было видно как браузер что-то грузит и потом выдал уже скачанный файл в загрузках.

Comment: а что по поводу кодов ответов от сервера при аякс запросе и при помещении в iframe? На чем сервер писали, какие заголовки отсылали? Какая версия хрома? Я поднимал сервер на nodejs. Интересно разобраться, почему так по-разному отрабаывает один и тот же сценарий.